# Error al subir archivos en formulario y enviar al controllador. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

En un fomulario tengo un input de tipo 'File' para subir un archivo y obtener el valor de ese archivo en el controlador, pero al hacer dd($request->file('file') me muestra NULL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/save'), ['id' => 'Form'], ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'], ['files'=> true]) }}

{{Form::file('file')}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: Correcto. Puedes agregar el código de tu controlador? Estás usando el storage publico o privado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antes que nada deberías modificar la URL objetivo. Trabajar con la ruta `save` te puede ocasionar problemas. Lo mejor sería agregar `{{ route('incapacidad.store' }}` (o como se llame tu ruta, espero que me entiendas claramente).

Dado que no publicaste el código del controlador, veamos un ejemplo.

Supongamos que tenemos un controlador llamado `IncapacidadesController`.

Como es bien sabido, el método Store solicita el Request. Quedando así:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //Toda la lógica debe ir aquí
}
```

Ahora, donde dice "Toda la lógica debe ir aquí" debes ingresar algo similar a esto:

```
  $incapacidad = new File();

  $file  =  $request->file('file');
  $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $path = $file->storeAs('public/incapacidades', $name);
  //dd($path); //Con esto puedes verificar la ruta donde se guardará el archivo
  $incapacidad->file= $name; 


  $incapacidad->save();
```

Hay muchas maneras de almacenar la información. Espero que te haya servido.